# Use NVL with date conversion function returns ORA-01843: not a valid month error

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle11g

I have  the below SQL (Oracle) that is erroring with `ORA-01843: not a valid month` error when I do not pass dates into the `:P_FROM_DATE` and `:P_TO_DATE` parameters. For some reason it is not accepting the alternate date values (sysdate-30, sysdate-1).

It does work properly if I pass dates into the two parameters. How can I modify this to work?

```
AND pha.CREATION_DATE BETWEEN     
  NVL(to_date(to_char((:P_FROM_DATE),'YYYY-MM-DD')||' 00:00:00','YYYY-MM-DD HH24:Mi:SS') , sysdate-30)
AND 
  NVL( to_date(to_char((:P_TO_DATE),'YYYY-MM-DD')||' 23:59:59','YYYY-MM-DD HH24:Mi:SS')  , sysdate-1)
```

Comment: Can you show the exact SQL that's failing? As you have it, yes, you'd have to pass in dates. 'sysdate' is a built-in function: it will very much depend on how you're trying to pass it in. If, for example, you're using SQLDeveloper and saying 'sysdate' in the bind dialog, that will bind the string 'sysdate' instead of evaluating the function and binding the result.

Answer (score 1):

That's because you applied `NVL` function on the wrong place. You should apply it to parameters themselves, not the whole expression:

```
AND pha.CREATION_DATE BETWEEN 
  to_date(nvl(:P_FROM_DATE, to_char(sysdate - 30, 'yyyy-mm-dd')) ||' 00:00:00', 'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:Mi:SS')
AND 
  to_date(nvl(:P_TO_DATE  , to_char(sysdate - 1 , 'yyyy-mm-dd')) ||' 23:59:59', 'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:Mi:SS');
```

For example (in which I use SQL*Plus and substitution variables; you'd still use bind ones in your code):

```
SQL> with pha (name, creation_date) as
  2    (select 'Little', date '2022-11-01' from dual union all
  3     select 'Foot'  , date '2019-08-25' from dual
  4    )
  5  select *
  6  from pha
  7  where 1 = 1
  8  AND pha.CREATION_DATE BETWEEN
  9    to_date(nvl('&P_FROM_DATE', to_char(sysdate - 30, 'yyyy-mm-dd')) ||' 00:00:00', 'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:Mi:SS')
 10  AND
 11    to_date(nvl('&P_TO_DATE'  , to_char(sysdate - 1 , 'yyyy-mm-dd')) ||' 23:59:59', 'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:Mi:SS');
Enter value for p_from_date:                 --> NULL values passed to
Enter value for p_to_date:                   --> both parameters

NAME   CREATION_D
------ ----------
Little 2022-11-01

SQL>
```

Or, with values passed to the query:

```
SQL> /
Enter value for p_from_date: 2019-07-13
Enter value for p_to_date: 2019-09-30

NAME   CREATION_D
------ ----------
Foot   2019-08-25

SQL>
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for the response! When I pass dates into the parameters, I am now getting this error: `ORA-01830: date format picture ends before converting entire input string`  Any ideas on this?

Comment: Yes; you didn't enter data in format that is expected. If code says YYYY-MM-DD, then you should enter it that way, e.g. 2022-11-04.

Comment: Unfortunately, the application already formats it as MM-DD-YYYY and I don't have a way to change that.

Comment: Then change format used in TO_DATE and TO_CHAR functions' calls so that it works correctly.